# removeChild() Only Removing One li element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is my code:

```js
let span = document.querySelector("span");
let ul = document.querySelector("ul");
let li = document.querySelector("li");

//delete todos
span.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  li.removeChild(span);
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>To-do List</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 1</li>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 2</li>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When the span tags are clicked, the X text should go away. By running the code I have, it is only removing the first span only, not the other two. I have tried switching the statement let li = document.querySelectorAll(“li”) to see if that would work, but no luck. How should I proceed to make this work?

Comment: `querySelector` selects the first match, so only your first span has an event listener

Comment: `document.querySelector("span");` this only selects the first span, so you only add the event to the first span. You have to either attach the events to the other spans as well, or delegate it to the `<ul>` parent element. `querySelectorAll()` will return a nodelist you have to loop over, hence `document.querySelectorAll("span").addEventListener()` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Shilly & j08691's comments...

You can use querySelectorAll() to select all the matching elements instead of the first.  Then iterate over the NodeList to attach your listeners.

To simplify "knowing the parent" I like to use parentNode.

```js
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

//delete todos
spans.forEach(function(span){
  span.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>To-do List</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 1</li>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 2</li>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//You can use simple javascript concept
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.remove();
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>To-do List</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <ul>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 1</li>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 2</li>
    <li><span>X</span>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```